# Issue In VBA Script which finds each row with value 0

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new with Vba scripting and need help in my vba script

Expectation:

If excel data is as Follows:

```
R/C    Col1 Col2 Col3
Row1    1     1    1
Row2    0     0    0
Row3    1     0    1
Row4    0     0    0
```

Output should be either list of all rows with value 0 
In above example it will output Row2 and Row4

Code:

```
 Sub LookUp()
 Dim result As String
 Dim i As Long
 Dim j As Long
 For i = 2 To Rows.Count
 result = "Pass"
  For j = 2 To Columns.Count
    If Cells(i, j).Value = 0 Then
      Continue
    ElseIf j = 2 And IsEmpty(Cells(i, j).Value) Then
      result = "End"
      Exit For
    ElseIf IsEmpty(Cells(i, j).Value) Then
      Exit For
    Else
      result = ""
      Exit For
   End If
  Next j
 If result = "Pass" Then
   Cells(i, j + 5).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
 ElseIf result = "End" Then
   Exit For
 End If
 Next i
 End Sub
```

> Error: Sub or Function not defined

(This error comes after adding if else condition)

Comment: `Continue`... what is that?

Comment: I want to increment j if value is 0.
Referred this document -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/continue-statement  @BigBen

Comment: That's `VB.Net`, not `VBA`. They are different.

Comment: Please *indent* your code when posting - it makes it much easier for us (and you!) to read.

Answer (score 0):

May be

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rg As Range, s As String, r As Long
    For r = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rg = Range("A" & r).Resize(, 3)
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rg, 0, rg, "<>""") = 3 Then
            s = s & IIf(s = Empty, Empty, ",") & r
        End If
    Next r
    MsgBox "Rows: " & vbCrLf & s
End Sub
```